# Cannot access members in List of Class in Class

Tags: c#

I have defined a `List<>` of class `tRec` inside a class `tBot`. I can Add new items to the `List<>`, but I cannot access class members of `tRec` stored inside this list. When trying to access `tRec`-class members, Intellisense does not list the members.

Simplified code is as follows (stripped most members etc):

```
class tRec
{
    int Action { get; set; }

    public tRec(int action)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}

class tBot
{
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public List<tRec> recList;

    public tBot(double score)
    {
        Score = score;
        recList = new List<tRec>();
    }
}

static void buyToOpen(int Idx, tBot bot)
{
    double cumPL = 0.0;

    bot.recList.Add(new tRec(0));

    if (bot.recList.Count() > 1)
    {
        cumPL = bot.recList[0].Action ?? /Equals/GetHashCode/GetType/ToString
    }
}
```

So where I try to access the `List<>` `bot.recList[0].` with an index, I would expect that I could choose the class members of `tRec`, in this simplefied example `Action`, but all Intellisense provides is

> Equals/GetHashCode/ etc.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `public` the property

```
public int Action { get; set; }
```

If you don't specify an [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx), it defaults to `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

- `Count` is a property, not a method. Remove the parentheses.
- `Action` is declared without access specifier and thus is private, causing it to be invisible outside `tRec`. Add `internal` or better `public` to the declaration.